# How to size an iOS UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

So I have a `UIDatePicker` in my app.

When I run my app on the simulator this is displayed, with only one complete row being displayed either side of the selected time.

[image: Simulator. Only one number either side]

When I deploy the app to my iPhone, this is displayed, with two complete rows being displayed either side of the selected time.

[image]

This error is returned when running on the real device:

> [UIPickerView setFrame:]: invalid height value 196.0 pinned to 180.0

This error, and other similar questions lead me to believe I shouldn't be able to change the height of the `UIDatePicker`.

My question is, is it possible to produce a `UIDatePicker` like the one being displayed in the simulator on real devices and if so, how?

Thanks,

Liam

Comment: Yes it's possible, of course, but you need to take in account the kind of device where you visualize it and the constraints you set for it, can you share the code where you create the `UIDatePicker`? Or you create it using Interface Builder?

Comment: @VictorSigler Created using interface builder. I have set its height as a constraint. I have simulated on the same device.

Comment: Been there before, you need to add constraints for width.  I did add leading and tailing then it fixed.